# Having an issue using the post method with javascript

Tags: javascript, post

Im playing with some basic javascript on a website and I'm having some issues. When I run this function it redirects to the page I want and only posts the size parameter. How do I post the cost parameter as well? The syntax is really confusing me. O.o

```
<script>
function selectcratesize(size, cost) {
 var form = document.createElement("form");
 input = document.createElement("input");
 crate = document.createElement("crate");

 form.action = "https://www.example.com";
 form.method = "post"

 input.name = "username";
 input.value = size;
 crate.name = "cost";
 crate.value  = cost;

 form.appendChild(input);
 form.appendChild(crate);

 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "crate" element in html:

`crate = document.createElement("crate");`

should be

`crate = document.createElement("input");`

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I didn't understand the relationship between what was in quotations and what was before the equals sign. Appreciate it!

Comment: well thats why I'm here isn't it?

Comment: If you do not know about the "relationship between what was in quotations and what was before the equals sign" my answer will probably not help you in terms of understanding. StackOverflow is not here to teach you the bare basics. That's what the [countless](http://www.codecademy.com/) [tutorials](http://code.org/learn) [on](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp) [the internet](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming) are there for. Also valid answers should be marked as such.